# Compile my VB.NET application for Mac and Linux

Tags: vb.net, mono, ide

I have just finished my vb.net application and I wanted to compile it with Mac and Linux as well.

I have looked around and found mono project... I tried to use mono to open my application but the GUI is not as it should be. so my question is: there is way to maintain my Gui even on other platform? If not there is an IDE for Mac/Linux that support vb.net? I use Xcode for programming in c but the GUI Builder is so hard to use... There are other simple IDE/Gui Builders?

Of course it will be great if I can build directly from visual studio or with some simple way as well.

Thanks for all future replies.

Answer (score 0):

Mono's VB.NET was not very mature. So you might hit both compiler and runtime issues.

If possible, evaluate and wait for .NET Core.